# If $A^*A\geq I$ and $|x^*Ax|\leq 1.$ Then $A$ is unitary.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory

$A$ is an $n\times n$ complex inverible  Matrix such that $A^*A\geq I$ and $|x^*Ax|\leq 1,$ for $x^*x=1.$ Then $A$ is unitary. How to prove it?

From the above conditions proved $\|Ax\|\geq \|x\|.$ but unable to prove the reverse inequality.

Here $x^*Ax=\langle Ax, x\rangle.$ So, $|x^*Ax|$ is the absolute value of $x^*Ax.$
$A^*A\geq I$ means $\langle A^*Ax,x\rangle\geq \langle x,x\rangle.$

Comment: By $¦x^*Ax|$ you mean the norm? Can you be more detailed?

Comment: $x^*Ax=\langle Ax,x\rangle.$ So $|x^*Ax|$ is  absolute value of $x^*Ax.$

Comment: What does $A^*A\geq I$ mean here?

Comment: @amnesiac I assume it means $A^{\dagger}A \succeq I$, as in that $x^{\dagger}A^{\dagger}Ax \ge x^{\dagger}x$

Comment: doesnt the proposition of $A$ is unitary already mean that $A^*A=I$ by definition?

Comment: Hint: the first condition implies that all singular values of $A$ are $\ge1$ while the second condition implies that the trace norm (aka nuclear norm) of $A$ is $\le n$.

Comment: Please explain, how trace norm of $A$ is $\leq n,$ if $|\langle Ax,x\rangle|\leq 1.$